# Firefox 12 on Windows XP can't print, black screens with Page Setup, no improvement with Safe Mode

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, printing

A computer running Firefox 12 on Windows XP is unable to print.  When I open the Print Preview dialog box, no preview is displayed.  Attempting to print results in a blank page or no output at all.  (The Print dialog does open, however.)  Attempting to open the Page Setup dialog causes the entire Firefox window to become black, and Firefox cannot be restored without pressing Escape.  Running Firefox in safe mode does not help: opening Page Setup causes Firefox to hang altogether until Escape is pressed.

The computer has two printers connected to it: a Kodak ESP 5 and a Brother HL-2270DW.  The problem is independent of the printer selected, and there are no problems printing from other programs.  Is there a way to recover from this without clearing the Firefox profile or restoring from a backup?

Comment: Is this behaviour repeatable after restarting the print spooler or the computer?

Comment: The behavior was repeatable after restarting the computer.  The problem is in Firefox, not the operating system.

Comment: Great. I've voted up your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to delete the `prefs.js` file in the profile.  Settings are lost, but the history, bookmarks, and saved passwords are retained.

Answer (score 0):

create a new Firefox profile..

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles#w_creating-a-profile